# MVC Routing: Defining multiple / separated items as a single route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

**Consider the following MVC route entry:**

```
routes.MapRoute("Content", "content/{route}", new { controller = "Content", action = "ContentPage", route="" });
```

**Works ok for:**

```
www.domain.com/content/test
www.domain.com/content/blah
```

**Also works for url parameters**

```
www.domain.com/content/test?hello=1
```

**Does not work for:**

```
www.domain.com/content/foo/bar
www.domain.com/one/two/three/four
```

- How can I get my route to accept /foo/bar or /one/two/three/four as
  `{route}`?
- How can I do the above and maintain teh ability to read url
  parameters by the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
routes.MapRoute("Content", "content/{route1}/{route2}", new { controller = "Content", action = "ContentPage", route1 = UrlParameter.Optional, route2 = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Note: Add the maximum number of optional parameters as required.